# Angularjs: routes and controllers without templateURLs?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use Angularjs's routing and controller without the templateURL?

For instance, below is my current routes, controllers, and template urls,

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/1.html",
            controller: "controller1"
        })
        .when("/list1",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/2.html",
            controller: "controller2"
        })
...
```

And I have `ng-view` in my html,

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I tested with the routes without `templateUrl`,

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/",
            {
                //templateUrl: "js/template/1.html",
                controller: "controller1"
            })
            .when("/view1",
            {
                //templateUrl: "js/template/2.html",
                controller: "controller2"
            })
    ...
```

the result - nothing is displayed on my screen. obviously the controller cannot be triggered anymore.

Comment: What is your real requirement? How do you identify the view without templateUrl?

Comment: I just want to use Angular's routing, not its template. I am thinking to use JsViews for my templates. I find Angular's templates are ugly with lots of ng-xxx.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses the $routeProvider Definition to attach a controller to your view. If you don't want to specify the details in $routeProvider config, other option is to let the application land on one page using something like  -

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
  })
    .when()
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

});

This way user will land on main.html. Now on the main.html you can include several different html templates like  -

```
 <div ng-include src="'js/template/1.html'" ng-controller = 'Controller1'></div>
 <div ng-include src="'js/template/2.html'" ng-controller = 'Controller2'></div>
```

Notice the syntax of using/including template above - `"'<<Path>>'"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use template with empty string.

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",
    {
        template: "",
        controller: "controller1"
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting template with empty string make error and cause recursion loading ; i solved it by just add the link of empty html file.

```
 return app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",
    {
       template: "dummy.htm",
       controller: "controller1"
    })
```